# Avoid JSON parse error when PHP returns whole error notices

Tags: javascript, php

I have some big PHP files which should return a JSON string but sometimes give error notices like undefined offset, division by zero and some others.

Now, I retrieve this with JS, like this:

```
var response = JSON.parse(res);
```

and when there's a PHP error, I get this:

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Because the error notice is just HTML code. Now, I don't have control over the PHP files right now, so my question is, how can I check that the response is valid JSON instead of a HTML error notice? Because the SyntaxError breaks the whole program.

Comment: Use a `try/catch` block. That's what they are for

Comment: Also if there is php error response status will be 500 not 200

Comment: @charlietfl thanks! that worked, answer it if you want so I can tick it as accepted answer!